# getResults is not defined error

Tags: javascript, html

I have used Google chrome to see why the end of my quiz is not working properly and why the results are not showing in the text box and it says that getResults is not defined but everything looks ok to me. Also there's another error that keeps appearing and it says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. Does this error just appear because of the getResults error or is it related to a completely different thing? Please help I'm so close to finishing the quiz but then this had to happen. Here's the code by the way:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1></h1>
<form>
<ol>
<li> How much are you willing to spend on a phone per month?</li>
<ul>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q1" id="q1_1"> £5-£10.</input></li> 
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q1" id="q1_2"> £10-£15.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q1" id="q1_3"> £15-£20.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q1" id="q1_4"> £20-£25.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q1" id="q1_5"> £25-£30.</input></li> 
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q1" id="q1_6"> £30-£35.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q1" id="q1_7"> £35-£40.</input></li>
</ul>
<li> Are you good with technology</li>
<ul>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q2" id="q2_1"> Yes.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q2" id="q2_2"> No.</input></li>
</ul>
<li> Are you looking for an easy to use phone</li>
<ul>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q3" id="q3_1"> Yes.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q3" id="q3_2"> No.</input></li>
</ul>
<li> Are you looking for a modern type of phone?</li>
<ul>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q4" id="q4_1"> Yes.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q4" id="q4_2"> No.</input></li>
</ul>
<li> How big do you want the phone to be?</li>
<ul>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q5" id="q5_1"> Big.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q5" id="q5_2"> Medium.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q5" id="q5_3"> Small.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q5" id="q5_4"> I don't really mind.</input></li>
</ul>
<li> Do you care about the colour of the phone?</li>
<ul>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q6" id="q6_1"> Yes.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q6" id="q6_2"> No.</input></li>
</ul>
<li> Have you ever owned a phone before?</li>
<ul>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q7" id="q7_1"> Yes.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q7" id="q7_2"> No.</input></li>
</ul>
<li> Do you want to be able to use the phone to get out of awkward social situations?</li>
<ul>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q8" id="q8_1"> Yes.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q8" id="q8_2"> No.</input></li>
</ul>
<li> Do you want to be able to access the app store and download apps using your phone?</li>
<ul>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q9" id="q9_1"> Yes.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q9" id="q9_2"> No.</input></li>
</ul>
<li> What happened to the last phone you owned?</li>
<ul>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q10" id="q10_1"> I got bored of it.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q10" id="q10_2"> It broke.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q10" id="q10_3"> The contract ran out.</input></li>
<li><input type = "radio" name = "q10" id="q10_4"> Other.</input></li>
</ul>
</ol>
<input type = "button" value = "Submit" onclick="getResults()"> <input type = "reset" value = "Clear"></input>
<textarea id="result">The right phone for you will be displayed here.</textarea>
</html>

<script>
function getResults() {
if (document.getElementById('q1_1').checked &&
   document.getElementById('q2_1').checked &&
   document.getElementById('q3_1').checked &&
   document.getElementById('q4_1').checked &&
   document.getElementById('q5_1').checked &&
   document.getElementById('q6_1').checked &&
   document.getElementById('q7_1').checked &&
   document.getElementById('q8_1').checked &&
   document.getElementById('q9_1').checked &&
   document.getElementById('q10_1').checked
   ) {
       document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Unfortunately, the iPhone is the right phone for you.';
   }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Works for me in both FF24 and Chrome 30, as long as the first option is selected on every question. If not, the code doesn't change the result box anyway.

Comment: It seems to work everywhere except on my site.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the source code of your page in Firefox's page source viewer:

Every `<input>` is wrong. You have this:

```
<input type = "radio" name = "q1" id="q1_1"> £5-£10.</input>
```

But the trailing `</input>` is unnecessary. You should have this:

```
<input type = "radio" name = "q1" id="q1_1"> £5-£10.
```

Also: Your closing `</html>` tag should be the last thing in the file, but you have it *before* your script. I'd guess that some browsers might ignore anything after `</html>`

You have no closing `</form>` tag, which should be just ahead of your `<script>` block.

You might find it helpful to add a `<!doctype html>` at the top of the page, and a `<head>` block like this:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
```

which will sort out the character encoding so that your `£` shows up properly.

**However** you didn't mention that your page is being embedded in another site. As a result, the following tags in your code aren't required: `<!doctype>`,`<html>`,`</html>`, `<head>` (the entire header block I suggested can be removed), `<body>`, `</body>`.

You still need to insert a closing `</form>` tag that's missing.

The problem you report is due to the containing page replacing `&&` with `&#038;&#038;` in your script block. This is a syntax error in a script block and means your `getResults()` function isn't parsed. You'd have to check the site to see how to include scripts without this happening.

Comment: @Keon Since I can't duplicate the problem on my test server, can you post a link to somewhere on the web where the problematic page can be found - I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @Keon You didn't mention that you're embedding your quiz in a page on another site. I have update my answer with more info.